# Discrepancy in reporting 500 internal errors between Google Webmaster Tools (Search Console) and Moz Pro

Tags: google-search-console, http-code-500

Google Webmaster Tools (Search Console) has found 27 `500` internal errors within my client's website but Moz Pro is reporting 62.

The number of `500` internal errors from Moz has increased since the last crawl, whereas Google Webmaster Tools has stayed at the same number.

Why would Moz be finding more than Google Webmaster Tools?

Comment: Search Console might not be crawling all your URLs. These errors might be intermittent and may not be occurring when Googlebot visits.  They might also be dependent on other factors to do with the request that isn't affecting Googlebot the same... cookie persistence, crawl rate, etc.

Comment: I would say pay attention to Google Search Console and not MOZ. Google is the one you have to answer to and does give good information. Work from what you see from Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internal server errors can have multiple causes:

- Code syntax errors that happen whenever you hit a particular page
- Problems parsing user data that only happen for a specific user
- Intermittent problems caused by something like the database going down

It is not surprising that different crawling bots find different numbers of 500 errors.   You may have some 500 errors that always keep certain pages from loading, but many are going to come and go, or only effect a specific crawler.

Your server logs are usually a better source for finding these errors than the crawl reports from Google and Moz.   Your server logs will also show the ones that are effecting actual users.

I routinely monitor my site for 500 errors using the logs and fix them as they come up.